# Cannot import name 'FillMissingValues from 'awsglueml.transforms'

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, import, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I'm using for the first time `awsglueml` package to use the class [FillMissingValues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-fillmissingvalues.html). I'm using Glue 3.0 importing the ML package as mentionned by the documentation:

```py
from awsglueml.transforms import FillMissingValues
...
dyf = FillMissingValues.apply(dyf, "demographic", output_column="demographic")
```

And I got an import error:

```bash
from awsglueml.transforms import FillMissingValues
ImportError: cannot import name 'FillMissingValues' from 'awsglueml.transforms' (/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglueml/transforms/__init__.py)
```

Why does the latest Glue version is not up-to-date with the latest documentation? `FillMissingValues` should be in the `awsglueml/transform` package.

Comment: Glue 3.0 does not support yet `awsglueml` package. I had to downgrade the Glue version of my job to Glue 2.0. This is not a correct solution, because some jobs could need Glue 3.0 features and `awsglueml` features. Hoping that Amazon will soon realease a Glue 3.1 with machine learning features embedded.